# Remote Control Ubuntu from Android

Tags: 13.10, android

This is not really an urgent question but I just want to know if anything like this exists.

I currently have an app for my Android phone called PhonyMyPC and it allows me to control Windows (7) from my phone. I get a view of the entire screen and I can use the mouse as input, keyboard, etc etc.

Is there something like this on Ubuntu?

I've looked around and I haven't seen something similar.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can try [Teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux.aspx). It will allow you to control your Ubuntu from your phone or another PC. Download the Android client from Google Play.
If you would like to set up you own connection, you may download one of the many VNC servers available for Ubuntu. You may want to read [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers) to pick up the one that will suit your needs. There are many VNC clients available for Android, like android-vnc-viewer, for example, so you may choose one to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

Controlling your PC from Ubuntu: Windows 7 & 8 have RDP built in, I use [Remmina](http://remmina.sourceforge.net) to connect from my Ubuntu Laptops to those boxes since they are hidden in the basement ;)

Controlling your Ubuntu from Droid: You can use a VNC client on your Droid like Pocket Cloud to connect to your Ubuntu PC.